# I want to separate digits and characters from list and write digits to a text file

Tags: java, jsp

```
ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
entries.add(visits);
System.out.println(visits);
```

The output of list is like this [wt45, wt45, wt45, 88ty, de66, wt45, wt45, wt45]. Now i need to separate and write digits in a text file can any one suggest to me how to do this ? I am doing all these workin jsp page .

Text file should be like this :

```
45
45
45
88
66
45
45
45
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. We can help but we are not here to code for you.

Comment: Look at the ascii codes

Comment: I had searched question but no were i found similar question to which i ask .

Answer (score 0):

Try it and put into your JSP with the example, hope below code will help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] visits = {"wt45", "wt45", "wt45", "88ty", "de66", "wt45", "wt45", "wt45"};
        ArrayList<String> entries = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String s : visits) {
            String result = new String();
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                Character chars = s.charAt(j);
                if (Character.isDigit(chars)) {
                    result += chars;
                }
            }
            entries.add(result);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there are really only ever two digits, then it hardly matters in this case, but you generally shouldn't do string concatenation in a loop. Use a `StringBuilder` instead.